# CSS Nav Bar Padding and Overflow

Tags: html, css

So I have a horizontal navigation bar styled in CSS. My issue is that there seems to be some bottom padding on the bar, but I do not know where it is coming from.

Additionally, when the nav bar becomes really narrow (resizing the window, mobile, etc), it overflows out of the encircling div. How can I prevent this?

Here is the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/m8pWa/

CSS:

```
 html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #E0F2F7;
}
.header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #81BEF7;
    padding: 1px;
    color: #FAFAFA;
}
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 75%;
    height: 2em;
}
.nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.nav li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
.nav li a:hover {
    background: white;
    color: #A4A4A4;
}
.nav-wrapper {
    background-color: #58ACFA;
    padding: 1px;
}
.wrapper {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 75%;
}
/* this centers the internal elements */
 .centered {
    text-align: center;
}
/* gives a main content window to the left that is 70% of the main */
 .content {
    width: 70%;
    float:left;
}
/* makes a sidebar to the right that is 30% of the main and floating right */
 .sidebar {
    width: 30%;
    float:right;
}
.sidebar ul {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your elements should fill the space naturally, and `.nav` should *not* depend on an explicit height. This will allow for things like `font-size` to change, etc., and prevent the children from overflowing the parent.

Here's the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/m8pWa/3/

Remove the height on `.nav`.

On `.nav li a`, change `display: block;` to `display: inline-block;`, and remove `float: left;`.

```
.nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 75%;
}

.nav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: great answer! the nav not depending on a height was enlightening. How would I remove the small border around the buttons now?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Aristides. Checking into the border now.

Comment: .nav-wrapper { padding: 1px; }... remove that ;)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to do with `padding` this time. You have your height set at a fix `height` I changed it to `1.74ems` and it was spot on.

```
.nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 75%;
  height: 1.74em;
 }
```

For the nav collapsing when the screen size is a set width,

You do not need to worry unless the screen size is 379px in width and to be honest, no screen is that small unless it is a mobile device.

In that case if you will need to support mobile devices and should look into `media queries`.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/m8pWa/1/)

Comment: I'll look into media queries for sure, thanks. (I'll accept in 3 mins when SO lets me)

Comment: They are very nice and easy to use! I am glad I could have helped and best of luck in your design. Here is a good guide on them, http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/.

Answer (score 0):

i guess the problem came from the height of 1px you added in the`nav`

```
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 75%;
    height: 2em;
}
```

i made changed it to 1.8em and it solved it

```
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    width: 75%;
    height: 1.8em;
}
```

also it depends also on the monitors, they differ in size therefor their display